# How do I graph 0 < Arg(z - i) < pi / 4?

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I go about graphing the region $0 < Arg(z- i) <$ $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: I didn't really know how to attempt it at all. I'll keep this in mind in future questions however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excuse the terrible images. They're supposed to be Argand diagrams (in the complex plane).

Construct a preliminary diagram. Start by constructing rays representing arguments of $0$ (horizontal ray stretching to the right to infinity) and $\frac{\pi}{4}$ (a ray bisecting the first quadrant stretching upward and rightward to infinity). The blue area in between (strictly excluding the two rays themselves) represents the locus of points satisfying $0 < \arg(w) < \frac{\pi}{4}$.

This gives this image for the locus of $w$:

[image: Locus of w (prelim work)]

To get the locus of $z$, add $i$ to $w$, and this involves a vertical upward translation of $1$ unit. That gives you the following image, that represents the locus of $z$, where $0 < \arg(z-i) < \frac{\pi}{4}$:

[image: Locus of z (as required)]

Comment: Honestly the images made me confused even though I already know this... Your explanation is great but you should put the images when they need to be and not at the start, the first image after the explanation of $\arg(w)$ and the second image at the end

Comment: @Holo I've edited to reposition the images, hope this is clearer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Lets divide $0<\arg(z-i)<\pi/4$ into:

$$\begin{cases}0\lt\arg(a+ib-i)\\\arg(a+bi-i)=\arg(a+i(b-1))\lt\pi/4\end{cases}$$

Now we need to look of what value of $a$ and $b$ both of them are true.

It is easy to see that $a$ is positive and $b$ is greater than $1$.

For what value of $b$ we get $\arg(c+id)=\pi/4$? When $c=d$, so when $a=b-1\implies a+1=b$ now for fixed $a$ we have $\arg(a+ib-i)$ increasing when $b$ increasing so the answer for the second case is $b<a+1$

Draw both cases on the same graph and where they both exists there is the graph you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

$$0 \lt Arg(z-i) \lt \frac{\pi}{4}$$

replace $z=x+(yi)$:

$$0 \lt Arg(x+(yi)-i) \lt \frac{\pi}{4}$$

$$0 \lt Arg(x+(y-1)i) \lt \frac{\pi}{4}$$

Definition of $Arg(z=x+(y-1)i)=atan2(x,y-1)$ (see [definition of atan2 here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)):

$$0 \lt atan2(x,y-1) \lt \frac{\pi}{4}$$

We know by the initial expression that the argument is inside the interval $[0, \frac{\pi}{4}]$. It means that both $x$ and $y-1$ must be positive numbers. Due to this condition, we can make the following substitution $atan2(x,y-1) = atan(\frac{y-1}{x})$:

$$0 \lt atan(\frac{y-1}{x}) \lt \frac{\pi}{4}$$

Apply tangent and simplify:

$$tan(0) \lt tan(atan(\frac{y-1}{x})) \lt tan(\frac{\pi}{4})$$

$$0 \lt \frac{y-1}{x} \lt 1$$

Multiply by $x$:

$$0 \lt y-1 \lt x$$

Add $+1$:

$$1 \lt y \lt x+1$$

[image]

> So basically your target are all the complex numbers $z=x+yi$ whose position is below the line defined by $y=x+1$, in red color, not including the complex numbers belonging to the red line, and above the blue line $y=1$, not including the complex numbers belonging to the blue line itself.

Comment: You should be very careful!! $\tan(y/x)\ne arg z=\text{atan2}(x,y)$ and $\tan(y/x)=\text{atan2}(x,y)$ when both $x$ and $y$ are positive! You have to show why both of them are positive here